# Importing FBX with multiple meshes in UDK

Tags: textures, 3d-meshes, udk, fbx, import

I need to import into UDK a several amount of FBX models (representing buildings) which are composed by various submeshes (walls, windows, roof...). I need to keep the individual meshes (can't use the merge option) but I also need to work with the building as a whole. Do you know if this is possible? How?

Also, is there a way to keep the textures assignment for the FBX models after importing them to Unreal? Doing the process manually (importing model, importing texture, assign to the material, assign the material to each mesh and submesh) for 100 or 200 models (to import an entire city from City Engine), isn't viable.

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer perhaps, but in my experience with other libraries, you are typically expected to maintain a single mesh per file import. Unity, IIRC, has the same deal with its FBX imports.

Really, there is nothing particularly problematic about simply separating the pieces into individual files, is there? You just need to track their positioning offsets in the original file, before you start splitting the parts out into their own FBXes.

Comment: No, Unity preserves the fbx mesh hierarchy (we ended up using it instead).
The point was to remove the need to save and load the offsets, but yes, the same result can be achieved by doing what you said.
thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make a prefab after you have finished with the editing? I mean, bring it all into a blank map, edit as wished, and then make a prefab of that and access it from another project..